# Fold cloth without animation

Tags: blender-internal-render-engine

I'm trying to make a folded curtain. All the tutorials I found show the process of animating the folding process with keyframes, but I'd like to activate the effect so that it happens in real time when I change the value between the two shape keys. Right now, the only effect I get is the vertex group resizing. How can I enable the entire effect? Grazie.

Comment: What do you mean by resizing? Do you just want to bake the anim to shapekeys?

Comment: yes. Make the result of the animation permanent, without having to play it in order to reach the second shapekey.

Comment: What do you mean by play it? If you have the shapekeys you can mix them in any order you like.